# TypeScript: is it possible to infer a type based on whether a function call succeeds?

Tags: typescript, typeguards

This is a distilled example based on much more complicated legacy code. Suppose you have a function like this:

```
function foo(val: string | number): void {
  if (typeof(val) !== 'number') {
    throw new Error('val must be a number');
  }
  // do something with number
}
```

Is it possible to write the signature of `foo` such that after calling it, the compiler infers that `val` must be a number?

```
const val: string | number = getVal();

foo(val);

// Compiler shouldn't complain here since a string would have cause foo to throw
const x = Math.sqrt(val);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) will do this. For example,

```
function foo(val: string): void;
function foo(val: number): number;
function foo(val: string|number) {
  if (typeof(val) !== 'number') {
    throw new Error('val must be a number');
  }
  return Math.sqrt(val);
}

Math.sqrt(foo(123)); // ok
Math.sqrt(foo('asdf')); // not ok
```

See on the [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=34#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUA3AhgGwFyIDOUATjGAOYCUBGcMAJgNwBQoksCyqmuBYIALYAjAKYkaiASPGt20eEhTps+IqXIUAPtLETEAbxaJEMYIjRQAngAdRcYLxxVEAQgC87xAHJd47y5GJiZQABYkcADuUqLRAKIkESRo3qqIgiDEiGKIWFJCegGsJgC+xogkolAgJEgAslhhAHSEAI4kUE5UrGUsDc1tHWjKaACMAEwAzFTdiAD0c4hwANZ9jaEt7Z0j3liEDMABswtScFBLy0A).

Comment: While not directly applicable in all cases [predicate type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) might still be interesting to the OP (though it forces the function to have a specific return value)

Comment: You might want to return [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never) instead of `void` for the first overload.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a `void`-returning function which has the effect of narrowing the type of one of its parameters, and if you are running TypeScript 3.7 or above, you can make it an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) and the compiler will take that assertion into account.  An assertion function's return type starts with the `asserts` modifier and is followed by the condition we'd like the function to assert.  This condition can either be the name of one of the function's inputs, or a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates) that says one of the function's inputs `is` of a narrower type than its declared type.  Here's how we'd do it with `foo()`:

```
function foo(val: string | number): asserts val is number {
    if (typeof (val) !== 'number') {
        throw new Error('val must be a number');
    }
    // do something with number
}
```

So we've changed `void` to `asserts val is number`.  If the function does return, the type of `val` will be narrowed from `string | number` to `number`, as desired:

```
const val: string | number = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "str" : 123;

foo(val);

const x = Math.sqrt(val); // okay
```

---

Note that assertion functions only work on `void`-returning functions, so you can't have a function that acts both as a type assertion *and* returns some value.  And there are other caveats (such as they [require explicit annotations to be called](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33580)).  But your question is so perfectly suited to assertion functions that if I didn't know better I'd think this was asked by one of the language designers in order to showcase the power of assertion functions!

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUA3AhgGwFyIDOUATjGAOaIA+iYIAtgEYCmJAlAVoYW1IYmw5EMAfWZtEAbwBQieSOCI0UAJ4AHFnCWZc7RAEIAvEcQBycaxJn9shfcRQAFiTgB3Oiw8BREq5JoZkKIDCDEiKyIWHSMVjYA3HIKAL5J8gD06YgAJnBEcAwszuRUbjDOMRIkMqkyEAjhQgTEZJQ0lVaIpgCyWM4AdCRYYLkMaPoAPIgADP0ArIgA-IgARC0riAQAjABMAMyJMijoQuyH9WDhAB5diL0DhACOJFC6OGeImYhwANZYqoggA)